# Macbook Air 4,2: "Boot error" with 12.04 live USB

Tags: 12.04, boot, live-usb, macbook

I have been using Ubuntu 11.10 on my Macbook Air 4,2 for a time now and wanted to upgrade to 12.04. The upgrade process worked flawlessly until the reboot. After rebooting, my boot partition didn't work anymore and now I have to fix that by booting into a live usb stick.

The problem is: No matter what I do, I always end up with a **black screen** showing

```
Boot error
```

and a blinking cursor beneath.

This screen appears after I select the live usb in refit and press return (or the ubuntu boot partition, or the live usb-copied-to-harddisk-partition). I also get this black boot error screen when I don't use refit but the normal OSX boot manager (by keeping ALT pressed during boot).

Note that I do not get to see any other output; not grub, not the linux loader, not the ubuntu splash screen - nothing except this message.

I tried unetbootin with the normal desktop amd64 iso and the desktop+mac iso, also tried both [converted to .dmg with hdiutil](http://www.danbishop.org/2011/09/09/how-to-install-ubuntu-from-usb-on-macbook-air-42-2011/), and both with the script that the [ubuntu installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir4-2#Basic_Installation_Instructions) suggest.

All of them give me the black `boot error` screen.

What can I do to get past this error? What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems my memory is bad: Using unetbootin with a msdos partition table + mac iso + dd'ing to harddrive partition actually made it boot.

Comment: Yes. After booting the live usb, I could chroot to my old installation and `grub-install --force /dev/sda4` - that made it work.

Comment: What does `grub-install --force /dev/sda4` do?

Comment: install the boot loader on /dev/sda4 (the linux boot partition). see http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ubuntu-on-macbook-air.htm#installer for the partition layout.